# Meteor Unsetting property vs setting to null

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, meteor, simple-schema

I have some fields (a timestamp and userId) that exist on a Collection and will either exist or not based on a Checkbox input.

If the user checks off the box, the properties gets saved with their Date and Time fields.

However, upon unchecking, I'm simply `updating` the `property` to `null` (as opposed  to `unsetting`). On the frontend, my `Helpers` see the `null` value and don't display the timestamp and userId (which is good). But, I'm concerned with the `property` still existing on the `Document` (albeit being set to `null`)

I thought SimpleSchema would see the `null` value and remove the Property, but I am wrong. Any foreseeable issues with doing it this way, or is it better off to be safe and make a separate `unset` call to just remove the properties themselves?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the schema

Comment: try `undefined` instead of `null` may help. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware `$unset` is the way to do this.

There isn't anything inherently "wrong" with setting the property to `null` in your DB. In fact I used to rely on this pattern quite a bit to differentiate between `null` data and data that straight up wasn't present.

I've since come to prefer either the data having a value (`Date`, `String`, etc) or not being set a la `$unset` as it:

1. makes the DB read cleaner in a GUI by not showing fields that aren't present at all making better use of the viewport
2. still allows most of the same JS Boolean coercion logic such as `!theThing.theProperty`
3. keeps `null` as a concept more pure and reserved for instances where `null` is truly different to your application code than `undefined`. These tend to be infrequent but I've definitely run into them.
4. Mongo (and more specifically Meteor's integration with Mongo) have some nuanced query behaviors around `null` vs `undefined` that aren't exactly the most intuitive thing to a newer dev in the stack and setting properties to `null` as opposed to `undefined` somewhat plays into that.